# Hiding the text inside of an anchor tag in CSS

Tags: css

I have a navigation menu that has a FontAwesome icon inside every anchor tag.  So the navigation's code looks like this:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard <i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings <i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Users <i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums <i class="fa fa-object-group"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Matches <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Servers <i class="fa fa-server"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
```

I am designing for mobile first.  On desktop, the menu will be a vertical one.  On mobile, I want the menu to be horizontal, so I want only the icons to appear.  Is there a way using pure CSS to hide the text inside an anchor tag but not any child elements?

Comment: Can you change the HTML structure?

Comment: a { font-size: 0; } a .fa { font-size: 20px; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do that. I'd simply wrap it in a span with a class. It also makes it clearer what's going on here.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="nav__inner">Dashboard</span> <i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="nav__inner">Settings</span> <i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="nav__inner">Users</span> <i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="nav__inner">Forums</span> <i class="fa fa-object-group"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="nav__inner">Matches</span> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="nav__inner">Servers</span> <i class="fa fa-server"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav__inner {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav__inner {
        display: inline-block;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On mobile you could make the `i` element fill the entire `a` element, and set a background color to basically hide the text.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
} 

i {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  li {
    overflow: inherit;
  }

  i {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    background-color: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Dashboard <i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Settings <i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Users <i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forums <i class="fa fa-object-group"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Matches <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Servers <i class="fa fa-server"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But if all I am doing is hiding the text, it will still take up the same amount of space, right?

Comment: You can use `overflow: hidden` to prevent that. If you can alter the HTML structure and wrap the text in a `span` it would simple.